# how to invoke all compile stages in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have `main`, `test` and `it` (integration test) `Config`s in my project, across multiple modules.

I have a root project that allows me to type `compile`, `test:compile` or `it:compile` to compile each stage.

However, I'd really like to maximise parallelisation by compiling all configs in one go. For example, the tests and integration tests are mutually exclusive so could be compiled in parallel.

How can I invoke all compile stages with a single command?

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own, using the fact that sbt tasks are parallel by default:

```
val compileAll = taskKey[Unit]("Run all compiles")
compileAll := {
  val a = (compile in Compile).value
  val b = (compile in Test).value
  val c = (compile in IntegrationTest).value
  ()
}
```

Comment: ```> compileAll
[error] Not a valid command: compileAll (similar: completions)
[error] Not a valid project ID: compileAll
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: compileAll (similar: compile, compilers, compileOrder)
[error] compileAll
[error]           ^
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in how/where you're configuring that.